# Is it possible to create a multi-project solution in VS2012 where some projects are already bound to TFS?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget

We are trying to create a multi-project template so that anyone on our team can spin up a maintenance application quickly. That part is well documented and fairly easy.

Our problem is that we want our shared common libraries to be a part of the solution with either the most recent code, or at the very least, have the projects bound to TFS so they can do a "Get Latest" on them.

Is this possible? We've tried putting the Source Control files into the template zip file and modifying the vstemplate file to include them, but VS ignores them when deploying.

We were also exploring VSIX and Nuget as the delivery mechanism... is it possible using those tools to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert on the inner workings of TFS so I'm not sure if it possible in there. I think that NuGet is a good way to go though, but it would mean extra steps as part of the build process for those common libraries as you'd need to [create](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package) NuGet packages off them.

You could then set up a [local repository](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/Creating-Packages/Hosting-Your-Own-NuGet-Feeds) and have people configure their VS to [point](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToAccessNuGetWhenNuGetorgIsDownOrYoureOnAPlane.aspx) to that local repository.

Whoever is in charge of the build process for those common libraries could then inform developers that there is an update and they could pull down from the local NuGet repository (note that according to [this](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.1#Force_Package_Update) you don't necessarily need to update the version # of your package but you could do it in line with any assembly versioning policy which your company has).

The purpose of the here local repository is for when you don't want your NuGet packages published for the world to see - which I am assuming because it sounds like you're distributing internal libraries and helper bits :-) I am not sure what the implication (e.g. if package downloading of public NuGet packages will be slower) if you have the local repository and the public one set up. Also, I'm not sure if there is a way (e.g. to package the setting in a VSIX or similar) to globally push out the details of the local repository or if folks would need to do the steps in VS manually.

HTH,
Nathan